# Using demonstrative pronouns vs. regular pronouns

Tags: pronoun, demonstrative-pronoun

In my German 1 class, we learned that there are pronouns such as the following:

[image]

But we also just learned about the demonstrative pronoun:

[image]

And I'm having trouble differentiating between using one set of pronouns versus the other in the following example sentence:

> Gibst du ihm dein Auto? - Nein, ... gebe ich mein Auto nicht

Since this is a unit on demonstrative pronouns, the correct answer was "dem." But I'm wondering why I could not just as well say "ihm." What's the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're completely right: you could just as well say "ihm" here, of course. If you then also use the "standard" word order (with the subject in position 1), you end up with a perfectly neutral, matter-of-factly sounding sentence:

> Nein, ich gebe ihm mein Auto nicht.

But the clue is already in the fact that in this sentence, they've put the dative object - "(to) him" - in the first position, which in itself serves to emphasise the dative object over the subject.

This effect is strengthened by using a demonstrative pronoun. "Demonstrate" comes from the Latin for "to show" or "to point", and demonstrative pronouns are about doing exactly that -- "pointing" at an object in either the direct (choosing stuff to buy at a store) and the more abstract (designating one of various options) sense. And in the way it is used here, this emphatic pointing at "him" has exactly the same meaning as saying "*that* guy" in English - you're singling him out for being particularly horrible/unreliable etc.

To recap:

- Ich gebe ihm mein Auto nicht. - totally neutral: I don't give him my car.
- *Ihm* gebe ich mein Auto nicht. - emphatic: I'm not going to give my car to *him*.
- *Dem* gebe ich mein Auto nicht. - very emphatic: I'm not going to give my car to *that guy* [out of all people].